# How can I use my specs for their intended purposes if they are in a separate namespace?

Tags: clojure, namespaces, destructuring, cyclic-dependency, clojure.spec

One of the examples in the [`clojure.spec` Guide](http://clojure.org/guides/spec) is a simple option-parsing spec:

```
(require '[clojure.spec :as s])

(s/def ::config
  (s/* (s/cat :prop string?
              :val (s/alt :s string? :b boolean?))))

(s/conform ::config ["-server" "foo" "-verbose" true "-user" "joe"])
;;=> [{:prop "-server", :val [:s "foo"]}
;;    {:prop "-verbose", :val [:b true]}
;;    {:prop "-user", :val [:s "joe"]}]
```

Later, in the [validation](http://clojure.org/guides/spec#_using_spec_for_validation) section, a function is defined that internally [`conform`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec/conform)s its input using this spec:

```
(defn- set-config [prop val]
  (println "set" prop val))

(defn configure [input]
  (let [parsed (s/conform ::config input)]
    (if (= parsed ::s/invalid)
      (throw (ex-info "Invalid input" (s/explain-data ::config input)))
      (doseq [{prop :prop [_ val] :val} parsed]
        (set-config (subs prop 1) val)))))

(configure ["-server" "foo" "-verbose" true "-user" "joe"])
;; set server foo
;; set verbose true
;; set user joe
;;=> nil
```

Since the guide is meant to be easy to follow from the REPL, all of this code is evaluated in the same namespace. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945794/5044950), though, @levand recommends putting specs in separate namespaces:

> I usually put specs in their own namespace, alongside the namespace that they are describing.

This would break the usage of `::config` above, but that problem can be remedied:

> It is preferable for spec key names to be in the namespace of the code, however, not the namespace of the spec. This is still easy to do by using a namespace alias on the keyword:
>
> ```
> (ns my.app.foo.specs
>   (:require [my.app.foo :as f]))
>
> (s/def ::f/name string?)
> ```

He goes on to explain that specs and implementations *could* be put in the same namespace, but it wouldn't be ideal:

> While I certainly could put them right alongside the spec'd code in the same file, that hurts readability IMO.

However, I'm having trouble seeing how this can work with [destructuring](http://clojure.org/about/spec#_using_specs). As an example, I put together a little [Boot](http://boot-clj.com/) project with the above code translated into multiple namespaces.

`boot.properties`:

```
BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.9.0-alpha7
```

`src/example/core.clj`:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [clojure.spec :as s]))

(defn- set-config [prop val]
  (println "set" prop val))

(defn configure [input]
  (let [parsed (s/conform ::config input)]
    (if (= parsed ::s/invalid)
      (throw (ex-info "Invalid input" (s/explain-data ::config input)))
      (doseq [{prop :prop [_ val] :val} parsed]
        (set-config (subs prop 1) val)))))
```

`src/example/spec.clj`:

```
(ns example.spec
  (:require [clojure.spec :as s]
            [example.core :as core]))

(s/def ::core/config
  (s/* (s/cat :prop string?
              :val (s/alt :s string? :b boolean?))))
```

`build.boot`:

```
(set-env! :source-paths #{"src"})

(require '[example.core :as core])

(deftask run []
  (with-pass-thru _
    (core/configure ["-server" "foo" "-verbose" true "-user" "joe"])))
```

But of course, when I actually run this, I get an error:

```
$ boot run
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Unable to resolve spec: :example.core/config
```

I could fix this problem by adding `(require 'example.spec)` to `build.boot`, but that's ugly and error-prone, and will only become more so as my number of spec namespaces increases. I can't `require` the spec namespace from the implementation namespace, for several reasons. Here's an example that uses [`fdef`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.spec-api.html#clojure.spec/fdef).

`boot.properties`:

```
BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.9.0-alpha7
```

`src/example/spec.clj`:

```
(ns example.spec
  (:require [clojure.spec :as s]))

(alias 'core 'example.core)

(s/fdef core/divisible?
  :args (s/cat :x integer? :y (s/and integer? (complement zero?)))
  :ret boolean?)

(s/fdef core/prime?
  :args (s/cat :x integer?)
  :ret boolean?)

(s/fdef core/factor
  :args (s/cat :x (s/and integer? pos?))
  :ret (s/map-of (s/and integer? core/prime?) (s/and integer? pos?))
  :fn #(== (-> % :args :x) (apply * (for [[a b] (:ret %)] (Math/pow a b)))))
```

`src/example/core.clj`:

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [example.spec]))

(defn divisible? [x y]
  (zero? (rem x y)))

(defn prime? [x]
  (and (< 1 x)
       (not-any? (partial divisible? x)
                 (range 2 (inc (Math/floor (Math/sqrt x)))))))

(defn factor [x]
  (loop [x x y 2 factors {}]
    (let [add #(update factors % (fnil inc 0))]
      (cond
        (< x 2) factors
        (< x (* y y)) (add x)
        (divisible? x y) (recur (/ x y) y (add y))
        :else (recur x (inc y) factors)))))
```

`build.boot`:

```
(set-env!
 :source-paths #{"src"}
 :dependencies '[[org.clojure/test.check "0.9.0" :scope "test"]])

(require '[clojure.spec.test :as stest]
         '[example.core :as core])

(deftask run []
  (with-pass-thru _
    (prn (stest/run-all-tests))))
```

The first problem is the most obvious:

```
$ boot run
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such var: core/prime?
    data: {:file "example/spec.clj", :line 16}
java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: core/prime?
```

In my spec for `factor`, I want to use my `prime?` predicate to validate the returned factors. The cool thing about this `factor` spec is that, assuming `prime?` is correct, it both completely documents the `factor` function and eliminates the need for me to write any other tests for that function. But if you think that's just too cool, you can replace it with [`pos?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pos_q) or something.

Unsurprisingly, though, you'll still get an error when you try `boot run` again, this time complaining that the `:args` spec for either `#'example.core/divisible?` or `#'example.core/prime?` or `#'example.core/factor` (whichever it happens to try first) is missing. This is because, regardless of whether you [`alias`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/alias) a namespace or not, `fdef` won't *use* that alias unless the symbol you give it names a var that *already exists*. If the var doesn't exist, the symbol doesn't get expanded. (For even more fun, remove the `:as core` from `build.boot` and see what happens.)

If you want to keep that alias, you need to remove the `(:require [example.spec])` from `example.core` and add a `(require 'example.spec)` to `build.boot`. Of course, that `require` needs to come *after* the one for `example.core`, or it won't work. And at that point, why not just put the `require` directly into `example.spec`?

All of these problems would be solved by putting the specs in the same file as the implementations. So, should I really put specs in separate namespaces from implementations? If so, how can the problems I've detailed above be solved?

Comment: You make a great case for why it is preferable to have the spec in the same namespace when using destructuring. It seems impossible to avoid the tradeoff of gaining a more precise interface at the cost of cluttering the code, but it would be great if there were... so I hope someone can answer this :)

Comment: I believe the intended practice is to require `example.spec` in `example.core` and just `alias` `example.core` in `example.spec` instead of requiring it...

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin That doesn't work; see my latest edit.

Comment: @SamEstep In the case of `prime?` it boils down to a regular cyclic dependency problem - You can't use vars of ns A in ns B if you also use ns B in ns A irregardless of whether you are doing it to write specs. I believe that the resolve problem you have mentioned has been addressed (but not solved) per this commit: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commit/4978bf5cee35f74df87c49720fa82de7287d60a5 (only on master now) - Reading from the source it should throw an error in your case "Unable to resolve..."

Comment: @SamEstep What you could try is to use the fully qualified ns for your fdefs and not require or alias example.core at all - Alternatively one might argue that if your code depends on the parser of a spec, the spec becomes an artifact of the code and as such should go into the code directly.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin From what I've read in the `clojure.spec` [rationale](http://clojure.org/about/spec) and [guide](http://clojure.org/guides/spec), it seems like my use case is perfectly valid and intended.

Comment: @SamEstep I don't really see why you and levand wants to put the spec into a seperate ns at all. In his answer he makes no argument why one should do so and the more I look at the issue you have elaborated here I believe that without some new feature his answer won't hold.

Comment: @LeonGrapenthin That's exactly my point. As far as I can tell, it makes far more sense to put the specs and the functions into the same namespace. I posted this question because I saw that levand's answer had so many upvotes, tried actually putting into practice, saw that it didn't seem to work, and wanted to see if I was missing something.

Comment: @SamEstep I re-read his answer and the argument he makes is readbility IHO. I have commented under his answer and illustrated another workflow that enables file separation without namespace separation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question demonstrates an important distinction between specs used **within** an application and specs used to **test** the application.

Specs used within the app to conform or validate input — like `:example.core/config` here — are part of the application code. They may be in the same file where they are used or in a separate file. In the latter case, the application code must `:require` the specs, just like any other code.

Specs used as tests are loaded **after** the code they specify. These are  your `fdef`s and generators. You can put these in a separate namespace from the code — even in a separate directory, not packaged with your application — and they will `:require` the code.

It's possible you have some predicates or utility functions that are used by both kinds of specs. These would go in a separate namespace all of their own.